# Pandas duplicate rows to unique rows with weight

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, row, rules

I'm trying to merge row in a dataframe where I have different inputs for one ID, so I'd like to have a single row for each ID with a weight.

My dataframe looks like this:

---

```
ID    A     B     C      D    weight
1    0.5    2     a      1     1.0
2    0.3    3     b      2     0.35
2    0.6    5     c      3     0.55
3    0.4    2     d      4     0.9
```

and I would need it to merge the A, B columns for ID=2 into a weighted average (0.3*0.35+0.6*0.55 for A, 3*0.35+5*0.55 for B). For column C I'd need to chose the value associated to the highest weight (C=c for ID=2), column D the maximum value (D=3 in this case) and the final weight as the sum of all weights (0.35+0.55). Basically, I need to assign several different rules to each row for duplicate ID's, and I haven't found how to do this.

I'm using python I believe pandas is the best for this, but I'm just a beginner here, so I'll listen and try anything you suggest!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd       
a = pd.read_clipboard()

def agg_func(x):
    x.A = x.A*x.weight
    x.B = x.B*x.weight    
    return pd.Series([x.A.sum(), x.B.sum(), x.C[x.weight.idxmax()], x.D.max(), x.weight.max()], index=x.columns[1:])

print(a.groupby('ID').apply(agg_func))

        A    B  C  D  weight
ID
1   0.500  2.0  a  1    1.00
2   0.435  3.8  c  3    0.55
3   0.360  1.8  d  4    0.90
```

This should do the job check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html to know more.